# MySQL function Create Table gives me a Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, database, create-table

I'm creating a login form, I created the database and now I'm creating the table with this function:

```
function CreateTable()
{
    $qry = "CREATE TABLE $this->tablename (
            'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
            'name' VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,
            'email' VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
            'phone_number' VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
            'username' VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
            'password' VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
            'confirmcode' VARCHAR(32) ,
            PRIMARY KEY ('id')
            )";

    if(!mysql_query($qry,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error creating the table \nquery was\n $qry");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that every time I try to login to test the form I get this error:

> Error creating the table query was CREATE TABLE ( 'id' INT NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT , 'name' VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL , 'email' VARCHAR( 64
>   ) NOT NULL , 'phone_number' VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL , 'username'
>   VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL , 'password' VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
>   'confirmcode' VARCHAR(32) , PRIMARY KEY ('id') ) mysqlerror:You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 'id' INT NOT
>   NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 'name' VARC' at line 1

So obviously there's a syntax error on that line but as I have no experience in PHP I just can't see where the error is!

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: What is $this->tablename? From the error output, I guess its empty..

Comment: I'm not sure but above the function Create Table I have this line of code:     function Ensuretable()
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $this->tablename");   
        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            return $this->CreateTable();
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: B.T.W. for new code it is probably better to use MYSQLI or PDO library instead of the MYSQL library. The MYSQL_ functions will be depreciated from PHP version 5.5 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

You are using quotes instead of back ticks. And yea, there's no tabe name being passed into the function it seems. Your function should look more like this:

```
function CreateTable($tableName)
{
    $qry = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName (
            `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
            `name` VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,
            `email` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
            `phone_number` VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
            `username` VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
            `password` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
            `confirmcode` VARCHAR(32) ,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            );";

    if(!mysql_query($qry,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error creating the table \nquery was\n $qry");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: field names, when quoted, should use backticks, not single quotes - single quotes are for demarcating data. However the SQL is failing because the tablename is blank

Comment: @user1746391 - a back tick is the forward slanting version of the apostrophe. Don't have it on tablet keyboard, ill copy from another answer here shortly, in the meantime, see my answer for a way to run your function without back ticks, and the table name filled out.

Comment: Short key in windows is ALT + 96. Hold the alt key an type in 96. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard . On my US QWERTY keyboard it is left from the 1.

Comment: Hi Perception, I copied your code with the back ticks, thanks for pasting it there for me by the way! however, there's still a syntax error message!

Comment: @Mr.Radical - ill keep that in mind, might come in handy one day. This tablet doesn't have an alt key though, so not today!

Comment: thanks for all your help guys I'm getting slowly there... now my code looks like this:                                                            function CreateTable()
    {
        $qry = "CREATE TABLE `table`  ...etc...                                 
but now I get this other error message "mysqlerror:Table 'table' already exists"

Comment: Look in your admin program, for example phpmyadmin, if a table was created. Because it seem that it is working.

Comment: yes I can see from myphp Admin that the table has in fact been created but now every time I test the form it says "Table 'table' already exists... how can I stop it from trying to create the table every time???

Comment: Change `create table` into `create table if not exists`. Stop  initiating your function CreateTable. ;-)

Comment: so where do I put "create table if not exists"? after the function or after "$qry =" ?

Comment: Yes, `$qry = "CREATE TABLE $tableName` should become `$qry = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName` . With this command you create a table if there is no table with the same name and no table when the table is already in your database.

Comment: yes now it's working fine but here's another syntax error message... mysqlerror:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table(
name,
email,
username,
' at line 1
Inserting to Database failed! and this is the code $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
                name,
                email,
                username,
                password,
                confirmcode
                )
                values ...etc...

Comment: @user1746391 same problem same answer. ;-)  `insert into '.$tablename.'( name, email, username, password, confirmcode )`. Make sure `function insert_into($tablename)`. With single quotes the behavior is different from double quotes. If you had used the double quotes you would need to do this `$insert_query = "INSERT INTO $tablename (name, ...`

Comment: I'm not sure I get that... what should I do exactly?

Comment: @Perception, because it is your answer would you like to answer back. ;-) I have tried and failed.

Comment: Great what a relieve. ;-) Accept @Perception answer and give me a upvote if you think I have attributed to you solving this problem.

Comment: Wow, this conversation took off! Had to make my way to work, glad to see the issue is finally resolved. Adding the changes you talked about to my answer - for completedness. @user1746391 - please do accept whatever answer you felt helped you out the most.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
function Insert($tableName)
{
$tableName = newtable;
$insert_query = "insert into $tableName( name, email, username, password, confirmcode ) values ("bob", "bobsemailadress@hotmail.com", 911, "bob2013", "secrete", "1");";


    if(!mysql_query($qry,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting into the table \nquery was\n $qry");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't know which code you have used for the insert, so I made some assumptions.  Furthermore, it is basically another question.

Answer (score 0):

table name is not came here

```
CREATE TABLE ( 'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 'name' VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL , 'email' VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL , 'phone_number' VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL , 'username' VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL , 'password' VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL , 'confirmcode' VARCHAR(32) , PRIMARY KEY ('id') )
```

It should be some thing like

```
CREATE TABLE `table` ( 'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 'name' VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL , 'email' VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL , 'phone_number' VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL , 'username' VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL , 'password' VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL , 'confirmcode' VARCHAR(32) , PRIMARY KEY ('id') )
```

so check your `$this->tablename`

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding `$this->tablename` with brackets, i.e.

```
$qry = "CREATE TABLE {$this->tablename} ( ... )";
```

Furthermore, you cannot use singlequotes to quote field names (these usually quote strings in SQL). You should use backticks (`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use HeidiSql to create your database and then make a connection you your form ???? it's  much easier. And when  using heidi you don't get any sql errors unless you write wrong php code for inserting,updating and deleting data into the database.